# compressing rar\zip avoid file getting corrupted?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip, rar, winrar

Which good rar\zip compression setting or method to avoid file getting corrupted? store- not compressing anything, just put files together. best- compressing as small as can, it may chance file getting corrupted

Comment: Data corruption is *entirely* unrelated. The effects are of course more severe with maximum compression. It is very unlikely the amount of data transmitted over a TCP connection (which is probably what you’re concerned about) will have any effect on the degree of corruption that occurs, so (compressed) file size doesn’t matter either. // That being said, I don’t get the point of this question. Please elaborate.

Comment: i use winrar, format -.zip, method - best. in 200 image file, 1 getting corrupt. 100 zip file 2 got corrupted. should i change to 7,zip?

Comment: file size doesn’t matter. just avoid file getting corrupted

Comment: Where are you storing these that they are getting corrupted? How line are these archives stored for? I have archives that are several years old with absolutely no corruption at all.

Comment: If you get file corruption just from compressing files, you have defective hardware in your PC. Check your CPU, memory and disks for errors. Change your SATA (or whatever) cables.

Comment: store in HDD. use SATA cables. it got to do with hardware too, not just  setting or method? you guys ever compressing 1000 zip file? it most got 2-3 file corrupted.

Comment: winrar or 7zip doesn’t matter right, which 1 you guys use? most people use 7zip?

Comment: While theoretically software bugs could cause corruption too, if they would occur that often, they would’ve been fixed already. It’s your PC and nothing else. I never had any issue with any compression on any machine. // Also, this is not a chat or a forum. Please stay on-topic. The topic being your corrupted archives.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a recovery record, so it will store additional information to help avoid corrupt.

Comment: That's valid for RAR files only, right?

Comment: Yes, zip files don't have this option.